# How to access videos from sd card

Tags: c#, video, windows-phone-8

I'm currently developing a video player for Windows Phone 8 which will show a list of all videos (Stored in phone memory and sd card).

I didn't find any way to access system reserved files and folders by using `ExternalStorageDevice` class.

```
ExternalStorageDevice _sdCard = (await ExternalStorage.GetExternalStorageDevicesAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

var folders = await _sdCard.RootFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

MessageBox.Show(folders.Count().ToString());
```

By using this code I got other folders but I didn't got system folders like Pictures, Music, and Videos.

As well as I didn't got .mp4 files which are directly on root folder.

Please Help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get it working (for now - as many files are reserved and not accessible by third party apps).

Normally to see files on SD card you have to register an extension - [point 2 at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Step2Registerextensions):

> To read a file, your app must register for a file association in the app manifest file and declare what file types (extensions) it can handle.

Unfortunately (as I've mentioned) many files are reserved ([list is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)):

> But there are some file and URI associations that you can’t use, associations that are reserved. If your app registers for a reserved association, that registration will be ignored.

So for now it is not possible that your App can see these files.